# Azure devops: error NU1101: Unable to find package xxx. No packages exist with this id in source(s): nuget.org

Tags: docker, .net-core, azure-devops, nuget

I have a package I push to a private nuget feed. Then a few other projects reference these packages. All is good, except when I specify a wildcard, that only works in vs, but apparently not when restoring via an azure devops build:

this works:

```
<PackageReference Include="MyLibPackage" Version="1.0.0.114" />
```

but I get the `unable to find package` error on:

```
<PackageReference Include="MyLibPackage" Version="*" />
```

snippet of the dockerfile the restore task in azure devops runs:

```
# Install the Credential Provider to configure the access
RUN wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/artifacts-credprovider/master/helpers/installcredprovider.sh | bash

# Configure the environment variables
ENV NUGET_CREDENTIALPROVIDER_SESSIONTOKENCACHE_ENABLED true
ENV VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS "{\"endpointCredentials\": [{\"endpoint\":\"$feed\", \"password\":\"$pat\"}]}"

WORKDIR /src

COPY ["MyProject/MyProject.csproj", "MyProject/"]

RUN dotnet restore -s "$feed" "MyProject/MyProject.csproj"
```

Comment: The restore runs in the docker build when specifying an explicit package version, but not for an always-latest version range?

Comment: @JoshGust yes that is correct

Comment: Is this a total build failure when using the wildcard? I know that nuget checks all sources in parallel, but it should only fail hard if none of the sources found a match.

Comment: @JoshGust unfortunately yes, it can't find any package. There's only 1 source, and one private library, of which I just want the latest.

Comment: Does a range of `1.*` change the behavior?

Comment: @JoshGust nope, tried that already. Basically everyting except a hard version number fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Azure devops: error NU1101: Unable to find package xxx. No packages exist with this id in source(s): nuget.org

I do not have much experience with Docker, I am not sure if this issue comes from docker container or dotnet restore itself.

But since you said in the comment:

> Basically everyting except a hard version number fails.

So, I would like provide a **workaround** to resolve this issue, you can check if it works for you:

Since we have to use the hard version number, we could add one more command to update the package to the latest version, the command line like following:

```
RUN dotnet add package MyLibPackage -s "$feed"
```

And set the WORKDIR in the dockerfile where the project file is.

@Elger Mensonides, Thanks for Elger`s contribution for the correct command line.

If we do not specify the version in the command line, it will add the latest package to the project.

Check the document [dotnet CLI – how to update a NuGet package and add a new NuGet package](https://codingblast.com/update-nuget-package-dotnet-cli/) for some details.

Hope this can helps.

Comment: Thanks, after some tweaking the Dockerfile this works. Thank you! Still a workaround though. The dotnet add statement is wrong, it should be RUN dotnet add package MyLibPackage -s "$feed" and set the WORKDIR in the dockerfile where the project file is.

Comment: Yeah, docker was quite a steep learning curve, but now I wouldn't know what to do without it. I accepted it as an answer, but have my reservations on it. Nuget is one of the remaining things that really sucks in the MS stack.